# CodeIgniter 2 File upload crash if import keyword found

Tags: codeigniter

I am uploading a csv file with this code.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; //config overiding
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv|xlsx';
$this->load->library('upload', $config); //loading upload library
```

it works fine but in csv content if there exist a word **import** CI throw an error message

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

and if I change it with **Import** it works fine.

and it only happens on live server

> PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2

it works fine on localhost.

Can some body guide me what that was..!

[image]

Localhost setting:

> PHP Version 5.4.3 WAMP Apache Version 2.4.2

Live Server setting:

> PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2

Comment: You mean if the word `import` exists inside the CSV< or in the filename?

Comment: and it only happens on live server 
in csv content it works fine on localhost.

Comment: Are you using Linux serve?

Comment: what version of php is your local host running?

Comment: I dont know that library very well but see if there is a way to export the data as text. Codeigniter might be seeing the word import as a php call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid I use PHP `move_uploaded()` & it worked fine